# MySQL Update CASE updates field with "0"

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a problem by updating my SQL-Table with the `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT number,amount,minimuminventory FROM artikel WHERE number=17;
```

```
+--------+--------+------------------+
| number | amount | minimuminventory |
+--------+--------+------------------+
|     17 |     10 |                0 |
+--------+--------+------------------+
```

I have an amount of 10 but when I update my table:

```
UPDATE artikel 
SET amount = CASE WHEN amount - minimuminventory - 2 < 0 
                  THEN amount=amount-2 
                  ELSE amount=99 
             END 
WHERE artnr=17;
```

> Query OK, 1 rows affected (0,01 sec)
>   Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql updates my table an sets amount to 0

```
SELECT number,amount,minimuminventory FROM artikel WHERE number=17;
```

```
+--------+--------+------------------+
| number | amount | minimuminventory |
+--------+--------+------------------+
|     17 |      0 |                0 |
+--------+--------+------------------+
```

Do you you see the problem?

Answer (score 6):

```
amount = CASE WHEN amount - minimuminventory - 2 < 0 THEN amount=amount-2 ELSE amount=99 END
```

The value from the CASE statement is the intended value for the `amount` column, but you're doing `amount=x` again inside the THEN and ELSE parts of it. Change it to this:

```
amount = CASE WHEN amount - minimuminventory - 2 < 0 THEN amount-2 ELSE 99 END
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Do you you see the problem?*

In your statement:

```
UPDATE artikel 
SET amount = CASE WHEN amount - minimuminventory - 2 < 0 
                  THEN amount=amount-2 
                  ELSE amount=99 
             END 
WHERE artnr=17;
```

The comparison is interpreted as boolean but not as assignment.

```
SET amount = (amount=amount-2) -- comparison as if amount is equal to (17=17-2)
SET amount = (amount=99) -- comparison as if amount is equal to (17=99)
SET amount = false       -- i.e. 0, because 17 != 15 or 17 != 99
```

That resulted a value of `0` in `amount` column.

Change your update statement as below:

```
UPDATE artikel 
SET amount = CASE WHEN amount - minimuminventory - 2 < 0 
                  THEN amount-2 
                  ELSE 99 
             END 
WHERE artnr=17;
```